# Creating a Ticket in remedy Using Java Code

Tags: java, remedy

I need to create a ticket in BMC Remedy using a Java Code. Can anyone share the java api(get the api's jar file) and some samples to create a ticket using that api in java.

I am unable to understand the answers in the 
[Create ticket in BMC Remedy via Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074599/create-ticket-in-bmc-remedy-via-java)

Comment: Please edit your post and explain what you don't understand about the accepted answer to the question you refer to.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the example posted on this page somewhere near the bottom is a working example to create an Incident Ticket using Remedy 7.5. Unfortunately, you must get the api from your Remedy installation, they cannot be given out.

https://communities.bmc.com/communities/message/108563

I have found freely available java doc available on these sites:
7.5: http://www.javasystemsolutions.com/documentation/thirdparty/arapiv75/
7.0: http://www.javasystemsolutions.com/documentation/thirdparty/arapi/

Answer (score 0):

Links to BMC Remedy Java API documentation may be found on [this page](http://arswiki.org/wiki/Javadoc_for_BMC_and_3rd_Party_api%27s).

You can apparently access other technical documentation via [this page](http://www.bmc.com/support) ... but you need to register an account.  (Thanks, but no thanks BMC!)

Comment: That link doesn't have java doc for v7.5